# HTML Symbol Entity - How to Float

Tags: html, css

How do you allow for a HTML symbol entity to float fixed to the browser screen. It is for a Sign-In page and I want to have a down arrow float next to a sign in link roughly 25px from left and 10 px from top in the corner of the page. Thank you

Comment: Show us the markup and the existing styling. Explain what “to float fixed” means; it sounds like an oxymoron. Note that it is irrelevant to styling whether a character has been expressed as such or using an entity.

Answer (score 1):

use `position:fixed` to the element style.

```
.fixedElement
{
  position:fixed;
  left:25px;
  top:10px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cQ6J/1)